# Eliminar redundância de código em um laço while

Tags: python, loop, while

Nesse exemplo:

. Pedir a data de hoje através de um formulário.

. Verificar se foi digitado no formato dd/mm/aaaa.

. Comparar com a data atual do sistema

```
from datetime import date

def verificacaoData():
  dataForm = input('Digite a data atual no padrão dd/mm/aaaa: ')
  while True:
    if date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") != dataForm:
      print('Data informada difere da data atual.')
      dataForm = input('Digite a data atual no padrão dd/mm/aaaa: ')
    else:
      print('Correto! Datas conferem!')
      break

verificacaoData()
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer este código evitando a redundância da linha abaixo?

`dataForm = input('Digite a data atual no padrão dd/mm/aaaa: ')`

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@bragals/verificacaoData)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim?

```
from datetime import date

def verificacaoData():
  while True:
    dataForm = input('Digite a data atual no padrão dd/mm/aaaa: ')
    if date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") != dataForm:
      print('Data informada difere da data atual.')
    else:
      print('Correto! Datas conferem!')
      return

verificacaoData()
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/d1o6Ij) (mude a data da última entrada para a data de hoje). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dedkzqul-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/DateValidation.py).

É muito simples, faça o código para executar só uma vez, aí você decide tudo o que precisa ser repetido em determinada condição, aí encapsule tudo o que precisa ser repetido no laço.

A forma escrita originalmente não só é redundante, deturpa o fluxo porque ele pede algo depois que ele precisa ser usado. Funciona porque é um laço e antes já foi pedido, mas fica difícil entender.

Comment: Interessante! Sempre achei que o

`return`

só funcionaria retornando o valor de, por exemplo, uma variável.

`return media`